# Not Using Slim Jquery version but still this error occurs Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery code:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var newText = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
setTimeout(function()
{
    $("#studentsWorkingText1").fadeOut();
    $("#studentsWorkingText1").fadeIn($("#studentsWorkingText1").html(newText));

}, 2000);
```

});

It is throwing the following error:
*Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function*

**I am not using the minified/slim version of jquery.**

Can someone tell me why is it throwing the above error?

Comment: Can you update the code to a runnable code snippet which references the jQuery version you *are* using (from a CDN link) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Please give the html code defining `id="studentsWorkingText1"`

Comment: I tried running the code and it works completely fine. Even though 'hello world' appears on the screen and disappears immediately.  So I'm not sure what you're trying, but try to download Jquery locally and link it to the file. https://jquery.com/ or use the cdn link.

Comment: The problem is solved I was using the bootstrap CDN and that CDN contains slim version of jquery.
Thank You